# Unable to access the returned instance of a method in another class in java

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to access a populated HashMap from another class in java. For some reason I can't. I think the code is correct but clearly I am missing something. THe hashMap populates fine but I just can't get access to it.

```
 public class Main {
    public static String HospNum;
    public static Map<String,String> mapAllBreathTest= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException, SQLException {

                String str = //Extracted text file ;
                String HospNum="1234"
                BreathTestExtractorMethods BT =new BreathTestExtractorMethods(HospNum);
                System.out.println(mapAllBreathTest); //EMPTY HASHMAP RETURNED
                }
        }
```

The class being called:

```
    public class BreathTestExtractorMethods {
     public String HospNum;
     public Map<String,String> mapAllBreathTest= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();


        public BreathTestExtractorMethods(String HospNum) {
            BreathTestExtractorMethods.HospNum=HospNum;
        }

        public Map<String,String> NameExtractor(String str){
            Pattern match_pattern = Pattern.compile("Patient Name(.*)Date",Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher matchermatch_pattern = match_pattern.matcher(str);
            if (matchermatch_pattern.find()) {
                String[] PtName=matchermatch_pattern.group(1).toString().trim().split("\\s");
                mapAllBreathTest.put("Sname",PtName[0].trim());
                mapAllBreathTest.put("Fname",PtName[1].trim());


            }
            return mapAllBreathTest; //THIS IS A POPULATED HASHMAP
    }
```

Comment: You are not calling the method NameExtractor()!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Map` called `mapAllBreathTest` in the `Main` class. Then in your `BreathTestExtractorMethods` class you have another `Map` object called `mapAllBreathTest`. The `NameExtractor` is responsible for populating the `mapAllBreathTest`. And it's never called.

So in your `main` you should call `NameExtractor` method of `BreathTestExtractorMethods`:

```
String str = //Extracted text file ;
String HospNum="1234"
BreathTestExtractorMethods BT =new BreathTestExtractorMethods(HospNum);
mapAllBreathTest = BT.NameExtractor("RIGHT STRING TO PASS");
System.out.println(mapAllBreathTest);
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If the two classes are placed in different packages, then you can't. You haven't declared a `public` identifier before your `HashMap` variable. Omitting the `public` identifier permits the use of a variable only inside the same class and package, forbidding the usage outside of these two.

---

On second reading the problem is that you are declaring two `HashMap` variables with the exact same name. Your second class configures its **own** `HashMap` (because the class looks first at its own scope) and then, in your first class your are printing the empty, unconfigured first `HashMap`. Try differentiating the names like this:

First class

```
public class Main {
    public static String HospNum;
    public static Map<String,String> mapAllBreathTest = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //You can just use an empty diamond operator here

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException, SQLException {

        String str = //Extracted text file ;
        String HospNum ="1234"
        BreathTestExtractorMethods BT = new BreathTestExtractorMethods(HospNum);
        System.out.println(this.mapAllBreathTest);
    }
}
```

Second class

```
public class BreathTestExtractorMethods {
   public String HospNum;
   public Map<String,String> mapAllBreathTest= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

   public BreathTestExtractorMethods(String HospNum) {
       BreathTestExtractorMethods.HospNum=HospNum;
   }

   public void NameExtractor(String str){
       Pattern match_pattern = Pattern.compile("Patient Name(.*)Date",Pattern.DOTALL);
       Matcher matchermatch_pattern = match_pattern.matcher(str);
       if (matchermatch_pattern.find()) {
           String[] PtName = matchermatch_pattern.group(1).toString().trim().split("\\s");
           Main.mapAllBreathTest.put("Sname",PtName[0].trim());
           Main.mapAllBreathTest.put("Fname",PtName[1].trim());
        }
        //return mapAllBreathTest; //You don't need a return type as the HashMap is already available in the Main class
    }
}
```

Comment: Its in the same package. I've now declared everything as public but still the same output

Answer (score 0):

You're hashmap is empty, Try populating it adding

```
mapAllBreathTest = BT.NameExtractor("stringOfYourLogic")
```